# How to found supported versions for Amazon SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

How to found latest supported version for an AWS service? Not `latest`.

For example for Amazon SQS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current API version for SQS is `2012-11-05`, as noted at the top of each page of the [SQS API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html).

Most services list their current API Version this way -- at the top of each page in the API Reference for that service.

The AWS service APIs are usually very stable, so AWS doesn't always bump the version when enhancements come out.  That means the date `2012-11-05` for SQS doesn't imply that the API is completely unchanged for 5+ years.  Instead, it means that no *breaking* changes have occurred to the API, and libraries written against any iteration of the `2012-11-05` SQS API will continue to work for all the features that particular library implements, going forward.

There is essentially never a need to specify an older version, nor a need to change the version you reference in any particular project of yours to a newer API version, unless you are trying to use a new feature that is only a available via the newer API release... which generally means your supporting libraries/SDK would need upgrades as well... so once you configure this, there's not often a need to change it.

Comment: The online version of the SQS API Reference no longer seems to note the version at the top of each page, but if you download the .pdf version, it is listed on the title page of that document.

Comment: @MarthaSeneta: It is now in bottom-right of every page of the pdf ("API Version 2012-11-05 87"). And as you said, it is not visible anywhere on the website - thanks for letting us know!

Answer (score 0):

There is a full list of versions for 3.X services here:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/index.html

Answer (score -2):

A managed service, such as Amazon SQS, has one version. There are no lists of supported versions to have to maintain/understand.

Are you talking about different versions of, for example, a java library for SQS?

Comment: No, an API version. Aws docs says not to use `lateast`, but use `YYYY-MM-DD` as version for production. Where to find it?

Comment: @Anton, please include a link to the documentation you are quoting.